# Db2: no available conversion for the source page

Tags: db2, codepages, remote-connection

I'm usind db2 8. Try to connect to the database (on the remotee computer, using vpn).
While connecting I have an error:

SQL0332N  There is no available conversion for the source code page "1251" to
 the target code page "UNKNOWN".  Reason Code "1".  SQLSTATE=57017

I tried to set DISABLEUNICODE=1 in db2cli.ini, and aslo tried to set db2set DB2CODEPAGE=1251. But it did not help.

What shall I do in order to connect to the database?

Comment: Note that DB2 8 has been out of service for a long time - I'd suggest upgrading to 9.5 or 9.7.  Also, you don't state what platforms things are running on, though I suspect both are running Windows.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for reply

I resolve problem using `set db2set DB2CODEPAGE=1252, as 1252` - is a code page for db I try to connect (1252 - USA; 1251 - cyrillic, was on my side)